# Scorm reporting

Tags: javascript, scorm, articulate-storyline

I am trying to integrate a articulate SCORM 2004 file into our angular system.

I am loading the SCORM files using iframes

```
<script src="bower_components/scorm/custom.js"></script> 
<iframeset ng-controller="ScormTestController as scormCtrl">
    <iframe src="scorm_test/scormFile_da/story.html" name="story"frameborder="0">
</iframe> </iframeset>
```

My issue is that the SCORM players lmsAPI is not called when i finish the test. at the moment our api is just a skeleton to see if the calls are made

> function IsLmsPresent(){
>       return true; }
>
> function SetScore(args){
>       console.log('SetScore') }
>
> function SetFailed(){
>       console.log('SetFailed'); }
>
> function SetPassed(){
>       console.log('SetPassed'); }
>
> function Finish(){
>       console.log('Finish'); }

IsLmsPresent() i called when the SCORM package is first loaded but using javascript debugger i can see that it dosn't perform any callbacks in LMSAPI.js while the user is performing the test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by modifying Claude Ostyns SCORM wrapper. http://www.ostyn.com/standards/scorm/samples/proddingSCOwrap.htm#download

```
<iframeset ng-controller="ScormTestController as scormCtrl">
    <iframe style="width:100%; height: 100%" 
         src="scorm_test/lbScormWrapper02.html?sco=beoplay_da/index_lms.html" 
         name="API_1484_11" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
</iframeset>
```